# how to run two web apps in the same localhost with same port in docker?

Tags: docker

I have two web apps(example.com test.com). I need to run these two apps in the same localhost with same port(8080). Is it possible in docker? If possible can anyone tell me how to do else any resource where i can get some help?

I saw something in docker.com like multi container application. I dont know how to 
run my two apps.

http://app1.com
http://app2.com

I need to run like this.I may be wrong. If it is possible in docker?

Answer (score 4):

You could consider running:

- one container per app, each exposing the port 8080 (but not mapping it, meaning they are not directly accessible from the host)
- one more container [**jwilder/nginx-proxy**](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), an nginx reverse-proxy service, which can run on 8080, and redirect to the two other containers.
  See "[Automated Nginx Reverse Proxy for Docker](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/)"

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. 
http://localhost:8080/ your port and domain is the same, it means that it is mapped to 1 physical folder, and I had 2 folders in that root folder, one for one project and one for the second
http://localhost:8080/app1
http://localhost:8080/app2
This will work, If one program works, you can try putting the other in that folder, it must work too.